# Check in SharePoint online files in other geo-locations in SPFx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I am creating a SPFx webpart using react class based component where I am displaying the checkedout files from all the geo-locations using search api. When I select any file and click on the check in, the file should be checked in. This works fine for the sites that belongs to same tenant, but when I am trying to check in the file that is coming from another tenant (another geo location) it doesn't work. Is there any way other I can implement this? (Don't want to route to function app).

Example:

Let's say I have two geo location:

1. https://xyz.sharepoint.com (North America)
2. https://xyzap.sharepoint.com (Asia-Pacific)

Webpart is deployed in North America geo location (https://xyz.sharepoint.com). It is able to check in files that is coming from this location. But files that are coming from Asia-Pacific geo location (https://xyzap.sharepoint.com) is not getting checked in (giving error).

Thanks

I tried using PnPJs.